# How can you use the result of a function as a variable in another function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn how to use Haskell and now I have to make a program that takes a integer n and a string k and every letter of that string will be moved n places to the right in the alphabet. At this moment I've got the next code:

```
import Data.Char

main = do
    x <- read getLine :: Int
    y <- getLine
    caesar x y

result :: String

rotate :: Int -> Char -> [Char]
rotate a b = [chr ((a + ord b) `mod` ord 'z' + ord 'a')]

caesar :: Int -> String -> ()
caesar moving text= do
    rotatespecific moving text 0
    putStrLn result


rotatespecific :: Int -> String -> Int -> ()
rotatespecific moving text place = do
    if place < length text
        then
            result ++ rotate (moving (text !! place))
            rotatespecific (moving text (place + 1))
        else
            if place == length text
                then
                    result ++ rotate (moving (text !! place))
```

But I can't compile it because it still gives me the same error message:

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
28 |                     result ++ rotate (moving (text !! place))
   |                                                              ^
```

But I can't see what's wrong with my syntax. I first thought it had something to do with using a Char as parameter for my function but I was wrong because text !! place should give a char and not a [char]. So what's wrong with what I'm doing?

After some edit I got this, but it still doesn't work:

```
import Data.Char

main = do
    xr <- getLine
    let x = read xr :: Int
    y <- getLine
    putStrLn (rotatespecific (x y 0))

rotate :: Int -> Char -> [Char]
rotate a b = [chr ((a + ord b) `mod` ord 'z' + ord 'a')]

rotatespecific :: Int -> String -> Int -> String
rotatespecific moving text place = do
    if place < length text
        then do
            help <- text !! place
            h <- rotate (moving help)
            a <- rotatespecific (moving text (place + 1))
            b <- h ++ a
            return b

        else
            if place == length text
                then do
                    return rotate (moving (text !! place))
                else
                    return ()
```

Comment: You are treating `if` as a statement; just because it is in a `do` block doesn't mean the expression following `then` can consist of a sequence of expressions.

Comment: You also can't use `rotatespecific` to "update" the value of `result`.

Comment: There's several things wrong besides your parse error. What do you think `()` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem is that *every `if` must have an `else`*.  You got a parse error at the end because the parser is expecting more, namely an `else` for that `if place == length text`.

When you fix this you will have more problems, because you are treating Haskell like an imperative language, and that's not how she likes to be treated.  It seems like you think

```
result ++ newstuff
```

will mutate `result`, adding `newstuff` to the end of it.  But Haskell doesn't mutate.  Instead, this expression `result ++ newstuff` is the list that results when you concatenate `result` and `newstuff`, but `result` itself remains unchanged.

```
ghci> let result = [1,2,3]
ghci> result ++ [4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
ghci> result
[1,2,3]
```

`rotatespecific` must *return* the rotated string, rather than trying to mutate it into existence.  The only way functions may communicate is by returning results computed from their arguments -– they may not manipulate any "global" state like `result`.  A function that returns `()` is guaranteed to be useless.

```
rotatespecific :: Int -> String -> Int -> String
```

Delete the `result` "global variable" (which does not mean what you think it means) and focus on defining `rotatespecific` in a way that it returns the rotated string.

I would also recommend commenting out `main` and `caesar` for now until you have `rotatespecific` compiling and working when you test it in `ghci`.

Comment: I changed that, but now it says that with a lot functions the input parameters aren't of the right type, for example: Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char -> [Char]'. I don't know what went wrong there because I thought they were the right ones. 
And it said my input couldnt be tranformed into a Int when I used x <- read getLine :: Int now i use xr <- getLine let x = read xr :: Int, but i don't know why that does work

Comment: @JoesdeJonge that error message is usually because you have called a function with the wrong number of arguments.  The other question has to do with the way Haskell models I/O; when you start reading about monads this will be discussed.  To whet your curiosity, to do it a single line you would say `x <- read <$> getLine`.

Comment: I've now added my current version to the main text above. If I try to run it now, I get error messages from line 15 till the end, but I do not understand why. It even says it can't do text !! place even though text is a string and place is a integer. And the functions after that aren't accepted as well.

Comment: @JoesdeJonge you might want to make a new question about this if it's a new issue (it's a matter of taste, but keep in mind that SO is 50% is for your problem, and 50% is for others with a similar problem in the future).  In any case, "it doesn't work" is never helpful -- always include the specific error message so we know what we're looking at.

Comment: @JoesdeJonge but the short answer is that `do`, `<-` and `return` do not belong in a non-monadic function like `rotatespecific`.  Use `let .. in` or `where` to make local bindings, and do not use `return` (just say what you would like to return without the keyword, e.g. `if place == length text then rotate moving (text !! place) else ...`).  `return` is about monads in Haskell, it doesn't work like in other languages (and this is lamented in the community; nowadays the equivalent `pure` is used instead and `return` will probably be removed soon)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is an appropriate time to just show an example, because there are a lot of little problems.  I'm not going to fix logic bugs, but I've fixed your syntax.  Hopefully this gets you unstuck.

```
rotatespecific :: Int -> String -> Int -> String
rotatespecific moving text place =
    if place < length text then
        -- use let .. in instead of do/bind (<-) in pure functions. 
        let help = text !! place

            -- multiple arguments are given after the function, no parentheses
            h = rotate moving help

            -- use parentheses around an argument if it is a complex expression
            -- (anything more than a variable name)
            a = rotatespecific moving text (place+1)

            b = h ++ a
        in b
    else
        if place == length text then
            rotate moving (text !! place)
        else
            undefined -- you must decide what String to return in this case.
```

After you have this function working as intended, and only then, open this sealed envelope. ♥️

> ```
>  rotatespecific :: Int -> String -> String
>  rotatespecific moving text = concatMap (rotate moving) text
> ```